# How to use lightstep/otel-launcher-node as an OpenTelemetry exporter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, open-telemetry, lightstep

Before I was using [lightstep/opentelemetry-exporter-js](https://github.com/lightstep/opentelemetry-exporter-js), I can use my own exporters and Lightstep exporter at same time.

```
import { CollectorTraceExporter } from '@opentelemetry/exporter-collector';
import { NodeTracerProvider } from '@opentelemetry/node';
import { BatchSpanProcessor, ConsoleSpanExporter } from '@opentelemetry/tracing';
import { LightstepExporter } from 'lightstep-opentelemetry-exporter';

const initTracer = () => {
  const serviceName = 'server-trace-service';
  const tracerProvider = new NodeTracerProvider({
    plugins: {
      http: {
        enabled: true,
        path: '@opentelemetry/plugin-http',
      },
    },
  });

  tracerProvider.addSpanProcessor(new BatchSpanProcessor(new ConsoleSpanExporter()));
  tracerProvider.addSpanProcessor(
    new BatchSpanProcessor(
      new CollectorTraceExporter({
        serviceName,
      })
    )
  );
  tracerProvider.addSpanProcessor(
    new BatchSpanProcessor(
      new LightstepExporter({
        serviceName,
        token: 'myToken',
      })
    )
  );

  tracerProvider.register();
};
```

However, just saw lightstep/opentelemetry-exporter-js is deprecated and replaced by [lightstep/otel-launcher-node](https://github.com/lightstep/otel-launcher-node/).

I checked the source code of it and the demo, it looks like it is a "framework" on top of OpenTelemetry.

```
const {
  lightstep,
  opentelemetry,
} = require('lightstep-opentelemetry-launcher-node');

const sdk = lightstep.configureOpenTelemetry({
  accessToken: 'YOUR ACCESS TOKEN',
  serviceName: 'locl-ex',
});

sdk.start().then(() => {
  const tracer = opentelemetry.trace.getTracer('otel-node-example');
  const span = tracer.startSpan('test-span');
  span.end();

  opentelemetry.trace.getTracerProvider().getActiveSpanProcessor().shutdown();
});
```

Is it possible to simply use it as one of OpenTelemetry exporters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lightstep-opentelemetry-launcher-node` basically bundles the required things for you for easier configuration so this is not an exporter. If you were to simply replace the "LightstepExporter" with "OpenTelemetry Collector Exporter" in your code you can simply do this

```
  import { CollectorTraceExporter } from '@opentelemetry/exporter-collector';

  tracerProvider.addSpanProcessor(
    new BatchSpanProcessor(
      new CollectorTraceExporter({
        url: 'YOUR_DIGEST_URL',
        headers: {
          'Lightstep-Access-Token': 'YOUR_TOKEN'
        }
      })
    )
  );
```

The default `YOUR_DIGETS_URL` from [lightstep/otel-launcher-node](https://github.com/lightstep/otel-launcher-node/) is `https://ingest.lightstep.com:443/api/v2/otel/trace`

Comment: Thanks @BObecny ! Does this same code also work with `WebTracerProvider` from `@opentelemetry/web`? Before **lightstep/opentelemetry-exporter-js** can be used in front end too.

Comment: Yes `CollectorTraceExporter` can be used in web too with `WebTraceProvider`.